# SVG 64 encode repeating partially horizontally

Tags: css, svg

My first steps with 64 base encoding and i have an issue with the emoticon repeating partially horizontally.

Here the result and i have trying many different encoding apps with same result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfA2U.jpg)

I have tried all encoding apps with same result. Also tried background no-repeat and width and height with same result.

The code i have use :

url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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')

Comment: Without the SVG or the context in which you're seeing the problem it's impossible to help you. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is a chat app and i am trying to see if there is some padding issues or something else.

Comment: It’s not a problem with base 64 encoding, and there’s not enough information in your question for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems fine.

```css
.demo {
  min-height: 128px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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')
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention it was working in a browser and it is in a chat app so maybe i have to look further how the emoticons are setup.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me, remember to use `background: no-repeat;` to ensure that the background image of your SVG is displayed only once.

Also, scale the element which holds the SVG properly. It should work for you.

Comment: I am currently reading about the viewbox maybe this is what i am missing here.

Comment: OK my apologies and thank for the help it was my width value that was 2 px larger than my custom svg.

Comment: You can mark the question as solved